# bitmap hit testing error

Tags: actionscript-3, testing, bitmap, hit

I'm trying to get my character to bounce back when it hits an object in order to not allow it to touch the objects. My problem is when its touching 2 objects, it gets stuck and moves backwards because of my else statement. Is there any way I can change my code to not allow my character to touch the objects in the first place.

My code:

o1 is the instance name of the objects all contained in a movie clip and p1 is my charcter.

```
import flash.events.Event;

var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var hit:Boolean = false;

p1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);


var redRect:Rectangle = o1.getBounds(this);
var redClipBmpData = new BitmapData(redRect.width, redRect.height, true, 0);
redClipBmpData.draw(o1);

var blueRect:Rectangle = p1.getBounds(this);
var blueClipBmpData = new BitmapData(blueRect.width, blueRect.height, true, 0);
blueClipBmpData.draw(p1);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void
{
if(redClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(o1.x, o1.y),
                            255,
                            blueClipBmpData,
                            new Point(p1.x, p1.y),
                            255

                      ))
{
    o1.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
    hit = true;
}
else
{
    o1.filters = [];
    hit = false;
}
}


function moveChar(event:Event):void{
if(downKeyDown && !upKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_down");
    if(!hit)
        p1.y += 5;
    else
        p1.y -= 10;
}
if(upKeyDown  && !downKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_up");
    if(!hit)
        p1.y -= 5;
    else
        p1.y += 10;
}
if(rightKeyDown  && !upKeyDown && !downKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_right");
    if(!hit)
        p1.x += 5;
    else
        p1.x -= 10;
}
if(leftKeyDown  && !upKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !downKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_left");
    if(!hit)
        p1.x -= 5;
    else
        p1.x += 10;
}
}

function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == 87){
    upKeyDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == 68){
    rightKeyDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == 83){
    downKeyDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == 65){
    leftKeyDown = true;
}
}


    function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == 87){
    upKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_up");
}

if(event.keyCode == 68){
    rightKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_right");
}

if(event.keyCode == 65){
    leftKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_left");
}

if(event.keyCode == 83){
    downKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_down");
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I changed it to what you said , but now my character doesn't want to move at all :<

CODE:

```
import flash.events.Event;

var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var hit:Boolean = false;
var redSpeed:Point = new Point();

p1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);


var redRect:Rectangle = o1.getBounds(this);
var redClipBmpData = new BitmapData(redRect.width, redRect.height, true, 0);
redClipBmpData.draw(o1);

var blueRect:Rectangle = p1.getBounds(this);
var blueClipBmpData = new BitmapData(blueRect.width, blueRect.height, true, 0);
blueClipBmpData.draw(p1);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void
{
if(redClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(o1.x + redSpeed.x, o1.y + redSpeed.y),
                    255,
                    blueClipBmpData,
                    new Point(p1.x, p1.y),
                    255))
{
    o1.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
    hit = true;
}
else
{
    o1.filters = [];
    hit = false;
}
 }


 function moveChar(event:Event):void{
if(downKeyDown && !upKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_down");
    if(!hit)
    {
        redSpeed.y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        redSpeed.y = 5;
        p1.y += 5;
    }
}
if(upKeyDown  && !downKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_up");
    if(!hit)
    {
        redSpeed.y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        redSpeed.y = -5;
        p1.y -= 5;
    }
}
if(rightKeyDown  && !upKeyDown && !downKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_right");
    if(!hit)
    {
        redSpeed.x = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        redSpeed.x = 5;
        p1.x += 5;
    }
}
if(leftKeyDown  && !upKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !downKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_left");
    if(!hit)
    {
        redSpeed.x = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        redSpeed.x = -5;
        p1.x -= 5;
    }
}
 }

 function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == 87){
    upKeyDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == 68){
    rightKeyDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == 83){
    downKeyDown = true;
}
if(event.keyCode == 65){
    leftKeyDown = true;
}
 }


 function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == 87){
    upKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_up");
}

if(event.keyCode == 68){
    rightKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_right");
}

if(event.keyCode == 65){
    leftKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_left");
}

if(event.keyCode == 83){
    downKeyDown = false;
    p1.gotoAndStop("still_down");
}
 }
```

Is this what you meant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you will want to do is do a hittest based on the anticipated locations of the objects. In order to do that, though, you would want assign speed values, instead of moving the objects on moveChar().

```
private var redSpeed:Point = new Point();

//in moveChat:
if(downKeyDown && !upKeyDown && !rightKeyDown && !leftKeyDown)
{
    p1.gotoAndStop("walk_down");
    if(!hit)
        redSpeed.y = 5;
    else
        redSpeed.y = 0;
}


// in enterFrame
if(redClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(o1.x + redSpeed.x, o1.y + redSpeed.y),
                        255,
                        blueClipBmpData,
                        new Point(p1.x, p1.y),
                        255)) {.....
```

Then you can just move the object by its speed.

Comment: I tried the code, but my character doesn't want to move now. I added the code at the top. is this what you meant ?

Comment: I only meant that as a jumping off point.  You'll now have to actually use redSpeed. Probably just right after

Comment: Disregard the above message. It looks like it should be (hit) instead of (!hit). Also,  depending on the order in which moveChar and enterFrame are triggered, you may have some issues.  Might be a good plan to call moveChar from the start of enterFrame. That way you know for sure that redspeed is set correctly for for the fram when hittest is called. Hope that hell's

Comment: I understand the concept, It just sticks the character to the object if it touches though since the speed then gets set to 0